# User Defined Function help: "must be the only statement in the batch" error

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to come up with a function that I can feed a date to and it returns the financial period that has been set forth by the logic dictated by accounting.  The following algorithm should get me there, if I can get SQL to play nice with me.

The error I am getting is that "CREATE FUNCTION must be the only statement in the batch", and from what I gather "If" is a statement.  I tried using "Case" instead, and that threw different errors.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Get_Period
(
    @theDay Date
)
RETURNS Integer
AS
BEGIN

Declare @dayCursor Date
      , @period_End Date
      , @period_Counter Integer

Set @period_Counter = 1
Set @dayCursor = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@theDay), 0)
Set @period_End = Dateadd(ww, 4, @dayCursor)

While @period_End < @theDay
Begin

    If @period_Counter % 3 = 0
        BEGIN
        set @dayCursor = Dateadd(ww, 5, @dayCursor)
        set @period_End = Dateadd(ww, 5, @period_End)
        END
    Else
        BEGIN
        set @dayCursor = Dateadd(ww, 4, @dayCursor)
        set @period_End = Dateadd(ww, 4, @period_End)
        END
    End
    Set @period_Counter += 1
End

RETURN @period_Counter

END
GO
```

Some insight on my approach would be a nice thing to have.

Many thanks,

Nate

Comment: I think you have one too many "END" statements.  Try deleting the one before "Set @period_counter += 1".

Comment: The "Ends" have it, Foggy got it.  I was raised in VBA and you need to have an "END" for every "IF", force of habit.  Thanks much!

Comment: 'Accounting' and 'logic' in the same sentence? Just be careful, accounting have been known to alter financial periods to make financial statements look good. Often this kind of thing needs to implemented in a calendar table.

Comment: That's kind of what is happening now, but I didn't want to be responsible micro-managing the data.  I have a hunch that I won't be able to get away from it, though...